# Rich Iron Ore locations

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

Where is [rich iron ore](http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/Item:Chunk_of_Rich_Iron_Ore) mined from?

Comment: what, may I ask, is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical about this question?

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd imagine it's because you appear to have posted this question strictly so you could post an answer to it. Some folks regard this as poor form, though nothing conclusive was ever deciding regarding it on the meta.

Comment: I'd love to upvote and accept someone else's answer, but, alas, after 4 weeks there are none.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Central & East Lone-lands, East North Downs, Eastern Evendim](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Ore)

The Kingsfell area of the North Downs has great tier 3 ore node density. In Evendim, the Parth Anduil area between Tinnudir and Ost Forod is also node rich, but the mobs are a bit higher level. You'll find plenty of nodes in eastern Lone-lands while leveling there.

Answer (score 1):

Go check Lorebook or lotro-wiki.com

http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Resources

(scroll down until you find Ores)

That page shows locations for all of the resources in-game.

Rich Iron Ore:

> Central and Eastern areas of the Lone-lands and North Downs, Eastern
>   Evendim, South and East lake shores in NE Bree-land

Comment: I suggest that you edit into your answer a summary of the relevant parts of the linked page. Otherwise, it may be deleted for being Not an Answer.